# Launcher is not showing properly on full screen in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, launcher, fullscreen

1. **Launcher** is not showing properly on full screen when **Super/Start key** is pressed. Following is screenshot of this behaviour:

[image]

2.
However, when **Alt key** is pressed, it seems to be working fine as shown in the screenshot:[image]

The launcher in screenshot 1 should spread to fullscreen when **Super/Start key** is pressed, as it is properly spreading in screenshot 2?

**How to solve this problem, that launcher in screenshot 1 is also shown properly on full screen?**

Answer (score 1):

Click on the maximize button on the **Upper Left Corner** to spread/maximize it to full screen.

[image]